# How do you consume a SOAP web service with Java?

Tags: c#, java, web-services, service

I am required to consume a SOAP web service with a Java program I am writing. I have a basic test .NET service on my server in a .asmx file. There are a bunch of complicated examples that I found on Google but can someone provide a short explination for me? It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my .asmx file.

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="Example1" %>

using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace="urn:Example1")]
public class Example1 {

    [ WebMethod ]
    public string sayHello(string name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

}
```

Maybe there is a different way I should be doing this?  Thanks again.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:java]?

Comment: Depends on what Web service stack you choose.  For JAX-WS have a look at "wsimport" in the JDK.

Comment: You will likely find [this][1] answer most useful.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/291847/850326

Answer (score 4):

You can use a tool that comes with the JDK called `wsimport` to parse your WSDL file and generate Java classes.

```
wsimport http://path/to/your?wsdl -d /desired/output/folder
```

You can then use the generated classes like so:

```
Example1Endpoint example1 = new Example1Service().getExample1Port();
System.out.println(example1.sayHello("tkcsam"));
```

Comment: Would I have to create my own wsdl file then?  The one I was looking at was automatically generated.  I can view it by adding ?wsdl at the end of my service URL

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer.  It lead me in the right direction thank you! Here is a tutorial that I also followed that helped me get what I needed.  http://honga.super6.cz/2011/07/consuming-wcf-services-with-java-client.html

Comment: You do not need to generate your own WSDL file.  `wsimport` can work with the one generated by the .Net web service (the one you can view by adding ?wsdl too the end of the URL).

Answer (score 0):

Is your .Net service a "page" that you post a string to as a parm? I've had to talk to a few of those in the past (I wouldn't really call them "web services", but anyway....).

If that is the case, find out what you need to post. Use your Java to build the giant String that you need to feed to the page and then send it to the page as a parm and wait for the response String coming back. You'll have to parse that string then.

This is terribly inelegant, but it used to be how Microsoft did things. Not sure if it is true in your case. Otherwise if you do have a WSDL to work with then I'd probably use either Jack's answer or follow the comment by djhaskin987 as there are some frameworks listed there that will dynamically generate web service clients based on published web services (that have their WSDL published with them).

Answer (score 0):

JAXWS is the standard technology for interacting with SOAP webservices in java.  the default implementation in the oracle jdk is the metro stack, which has an [extensive user guide](http://metro.java.net/guide/).