# How to consume .net webservices using java

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consuming a web service in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291847/consuming-a-web-service-in-java)

How to consume the webservices(.asmx) using java?  I need to parse the response xml and use it on my application.

My webservice is simply for user authentication.

Is there any library needs to be added? I don't know the different possibilities of doing it since i am new to this.

Answer (score 3):

Webservice is a standard, so dont think about a .NET Webservice, think about consuming webservices in general. Here you can find further informations

[Simply consuming a web service in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291847/consuming-a-web-service-in-java)

Comment: in my case i need to build authentication system using java by consuming a.NET webservice.

Comment: yes i know. What is the problem ?

Comment: I am exploring the ways to do it.

Comment: If my answer is not enough please provide some more source code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: am sorry u misunderstood.I am asking any refernce code or example so that i can implement