# How do I connect to a WSDL service using Java?

Tags: java, service, web

I want to get end of day stock quotes using Java and was given a WSDLurl showing the xml.

All the places that I find on this topic want to show me how to create a service, and that is complicated. All I want to do is connect to the url and get the data.

This link seems close, but still wants to generate some xml code.

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html

Anyone have a simple java example where you get data from a WSDL url?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like your answer could be here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/291847/686036

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using something like http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html. Otherwise, you'll have all the pain of trying to deal with the SOAP protocol, and all of it's associated quirks and hoops.

Comment: There seems to be more about this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291847/simply-consuming-a-web-service-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wsimport`.

- Copy-paste solution

`wsimport -keep http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl`

- [Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/)